# toggling innerHTML in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to toggle between two icons by clicking on `.switch` and apply the style of `.nightTextNight` to `.nightText`, my JavaScript code works everywhere except here.

And can anyone suggest me any other way to make it simpler?
Because, for every little change I need to create two class and give it an id.

```js
var nightBtn = document.getElementById("switch");
var body = document.getElementById("body");
var header = document.getElementById("header");
var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
var nightText = document.getElementById("nightText");

function nightMode() {
 nightBtn.classList.toggle("switchNight");
 body.classList.toggle("night");
 navbar.classList.toggle("navbarNight");
 nightText.classList.toggle("nightTextNight");
 if(nightText.className = "nightTextNight") {
  nightText.innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-sun-o' aria-hidden='true'></i>";
 } else {
  nightText.innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-moon-o' aria-hidden='true'></i>";
 };
}
```

```css
body {
 background-color: white;
 transition: background-color ease 0.3s;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 font-family: sans-serif;
}

.night {
 background-color: #3f4b5e;
 transition: background-color ease 1s;
}

.switch {
 height: 35px;
 width: 35px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background-color: #092d30;
 border: 3px solid wheat;
 float: right;
 z-index: 4;
 transition: background-color ease 1s;
 margin-top: 12px;
 margin-right: 4px;
 cursor: pointer;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 17.5px;
 position: relative;
}

.switchNight {
 background-color: wheat;
 border: 3px solid #092d30;
 z-index: 4;
 transition: background-color ease 1s;
}

.textNight {
 color: white;
}

.switch:hover {
 background-color: #4d5e77;
 transition: background-color ease 1s;
}

.switchNight:hover {
 background-color: #fff2d8;
 transition: background-color ease 1s;
}

/* --------------------- NAV BAR ------------------ */

.navbar {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 background: #f4f7f9;
 position: fixed;
 margin-top: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border-bottom: 3px solid #2fb3f9;
}

.navbar li {
 list-style-type: none;
 display: inline;
 height: auto;
}

.navbar li a {
 padding: 20px 25px;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-weight: bolder;
 color: #516f7f;
}

.navbar li a:hover {
 color: #ff9d00;
 transition: color ease 0.3s;
}

.navbarNight {
 background-color: #556bb5;
 border-bottom: 3px solid white;
}

.navbarNight li a {
 color: white;
}

.nightText {
 position: absolute;
 color: white;
 font-weight: bolder;
 top: 9px;
 right: 12px;
}

.nightTextNight {
 color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">
 <title>Night Mode - TEST</title>
</head>
<body id="body">
 <div id="container">
  <div id="nav">
   <ul id="navbar" class="navbar">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About me</a></li>
    <li><div id="switch" class="switch" onclick="nightMode()"><span id="nightText" class="nightText"><i class="fa fa-moon-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></div></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `if(nightText.className = "nightTextNight")` should be `if(nightText.className === "nightTextNight")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wasn't working because you've got two classes:

```
nightText nightTextNight
```

So you need to check:

```
if(nightText.className === "nightText nightTextNight")
```

```js
var nightBtn = document.getElementById("switch");
var body = document.getElementById("body");
var header = document.getElementById("header");
var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
var nightText = document.getElementById("nightText");

function nightMode() {
 nightBtn.classList.toggle("switchNight");
 body.classList.toggle("night");
 navbar.classList.toggle("navbarNight");
 nightText.classList.toggle("nightTextNight");
 if(nightText.className === "nightText nightTextNight") {
  nightText.innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-sun-o' aria-hidden='true'></i>";
 } else {
  nightText.innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-moon-o' aria-hidden='true'></i>";
 };
  console.log(nightText.className);
}
```

```css
body {
 background-color: white;
 transition: background-color ease 0.3s;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 font-family: sans-serif;
}

.night {
 background-color: #3f4b5e;
 transition: background-color ease 1s;
}

.switch {
 height: 35px;
 width: 35px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background-color: #092d30;
 border: 3px solid wheat;
 float: right;
 z-index: 4;
 transition: background-color ease 1s;
 margin-top: 12px;
 margin-right: 4px;
 cursor: pointer;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 17.5px;
 position: relative;
}

.switchNight {
 background-color: wheat;
 border: 3px solid #092d30;
 z-index: 4;
 transition: background-color ease 1s;
}

.textNight {
 color: white;
}

.switch:hover {
 background-color: #4d5e77;
 transition: background-color ease 1s;
}

.switchNight:hover {
 background-color: #fff2d8;
 transition: background-color ease 1s;
}

/* --------------------- NAV BAR ------------------ */

.navbar {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 background: #f4f7f9;
 position: fixed;
 margin-top: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border-bottom: 3px solid #2fb3f9;
}

.navbar li {
 list-style-type: none;
 display: inline;
 height: auto;
}

.navbar li a {
 padding: 20px 25px;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-weight: bolder;
 color: #516f7f;
}

.navbar li a:hover {
 color: #ff9d00;
 transition: color ease 0.3s;
}

.navbarNight {
 background-color: #556bb5;
 border-bottom: 3px solid white;
}

.navbarNight li a {
 color: white;
}

.nightText {
 position: absolute;
 color: white;
 font-weight: bolder;
 top: 9px;
 right: 12px;
}

.nightTextNight {
 color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">
 <title>Night Mode - TEST</title>
</head>
<body id="body">
 <div id="container">
  <div id="nav">
   <ul id="navbar" class="navbar">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About me</a></li>
    <li><div id="switch" class="switch" onclick="nightMode()"><span id="nightText" class="nightText"><i class="fa fa-moon-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></div></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

PD: I added `console.log(nightText.className);` to show the classes, you can remove it.

Answer (score 1):

You can just toggle the icon class instead of changing the entire `i` tag

```
var nightBtn = document.getElementById("switch");
var nightBtnIcon = document.getElementById("switch-icon");
var body = document.getElementById("body");
var header = document.getElementById("header");
var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");

function nightMode() {
    nightBtn.classList.toggle("switchNight");
    body.classList.toggle("night");
    navbar.classList.toggle("navbarNight");
    nightBtnIcon.classList.toggle("fa-sun-o");
    nightBtnIcon.classList.toggle("fa-moon-o");
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="navbar" class="navbar">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About me</a></li>
                <li><div id="switch" class="switch" onclick="nightMode()"><i class="icon fa fa-moon-o" aria-hidden="true" id=“switch-icon”></i></span></div></li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: Still not working, I copied and pasted the exact thing but still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

What about wrapping all of the elements that might have a `night` style different in a div, or even in the body, and then just apply a `night` class to that wrapper.

You could then add different styles to your elements along the lines of:

`.night .navbar {
  ... just night-related style differences ...
}`

Then, your toggle would only have to add or remove the class from the wrapping element. You would still have to add new classes for those things that you want to change, but it would only be for the properties you want to change on them.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to ignore the id to use an `Attribute` and `loop` like `data-mode`
see this example :

```js
 var modes={
 day:{
       switch:"switch", body:"day", navbar:"navbar",icon:"fa fa-moon-o"
  },
 night:{
       switch:"switchNight switch", body:"night day", navbar:"navbarNight navbar",icon:"fa fa-sun-o"
    }
 }
 function changeMode(arg){
  window.mode=arg;
  var elem=document.querySelectorAll('[data-mode]');
  for (var i=0; i<elem.length; i++){
   var key=elem[i].getAttribute("data-mode");
   elem[i].classList=modes[arg][key];
  }

 }
 window.mode="day";
```

```css
 body {
  background-color: white;
  transition: background-color ease 0.3s;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
 }

 .night {
  background-color: #3f4b5e;
  transition: background-color ease 1s;
 }

 .switch {
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #092d30;
  border: 3px solid wheat;
  float: right;
  z-index: 4;
  transition: background-color ease 1s;
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-right: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 17.5px;
  position: relative;
 }

 .switchNight {
  background-color: wheat;
  border: 3px solid #092d30;
  z-index: 4;
  transition: background-color ease 1s;
 }

 .textNight {
  color: white;
 }

 .switch:hover {
  background-color: #4d5e77;
  transition: background-color ease 1s;
 }

 .switchNight:hover {
  background-color: #fff2d8;
  transition: background-color ease 1s;
 }

 /* --------------------- NAV BAR ------------------ */

 .navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background: #f4f7f9;
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #2fb3f9;
 }

 .navbar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
  height: auto;
 }

 .navbar li a {
  padding: 20px 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: #516f7f;
 }

 .navbar li a:hover {
  color: #ff9d00;
  transition: color ease 0.3s;
 }

 .navbarNight {
  background-color: #556bb5;
  border-bottom: 3px solid white;
 }

 .navbarNight li a {
  color: white;
 }

 .nightText {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bolder;
  top: 9px;
  right: 12px;
 }

 .nightTextNight {
  color: black;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">
 <title>Night Mode - TEST</title>
</head>
<body data-mode="body">
 <div>
  <div>
   <ul class="navbar" data-mode="navbar">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About me</a></li>
    <li><div class="switch" data-mode="switch" onclick="changeMode(mode=='night'?'day':'night');">
     <span class="nightText">
      <i class="fa fa-moon-o" data-mode="icon"></i>
     </span>
     </div>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```